# sharepoint 2013 64bit Event 3759 Database not empty

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, configuration, content-database

I've recently just created a brand new sharepoint 2013 app server and I've been running into the following error in my event log pretty consistently at one hour intervals.

My event log keeps telling me: Database **'Master'** on SQL Server instance **'sql-sharepoint**' is not empty and does not match current database schema.

When I try and trouble shoot this I'm led all over the place and and can't find any thing that would put me in a position to resolve this issue. I have triple checked the SQL version to be sure that there are indeed no schema problems and I can confirm that my database were is a `SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 (Build: 10.50.2500.0)` and I've also double checked the collation type of my sharepoint databases and they are using: `Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS`

Comment: You sure it telling Master DB having the issue?

Comment: what is the Patch Level on app server? did you add app server in exisitng farm?

Comment: http://shareallthepoint.blogspot.com/2013/09/event-id-3759-database-something-on-sql.html

Comment: My app server is sp1 slip streamed, and I have not installed the most recent 4 patches. At this point I only have an app server an until I can resolve this issue then I will not be adding any WFE's.

Specifically this is the version of sharepoint that I am at: 15.0.4569.1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of pouring over different solutions, we found that the problem wasn't actually with SharePoint, but rather was a problem with our sql server cluster.

After upgrading from SP1 to SP3 this error was resolved.